Existence of orientable finite volume complete cusp hyperbolic 3-manifolds $\mathbb{H}^3 / \Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ has no parabolic generators?
Let $K$ be a hyperbolic knot, i.e., $S^3 - K$ is an orientable finite volume cusp hyperbolic 3 manifold. Let $M=S^3 - K$ then $M= \mathbb{H}^3/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ (Kleinian group) is discret subgroup of $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and also $\pi_1(M)$ is isomorphic to $\Gamma$.
Most of the hyperbolic knots I have seen above $\Gamma$ are always generated by parabolic elements, like 4_1 knot, twist knots, etc.. So, natural questions arise
My question is

Does there exist a hyperbolic knot such that $\Gamma$ is two generated Kleinian group where the generators are not commutative and not parabolics?
More generally does there exist a cusp hyperbolic $3-$ manifold $M=\mathbb{H}^3/\Gamma$ where $\Gamma$  is Kleinian group of two generators, generators of $\Gamma$ are not commute each other and they also not parabolic elements?

My attempted,
I think the answer is yes for 2nd one,
I am taking two loxodromic elements say $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ such that whose geodesic axis $l_{\gamma_1}$ and $l_{\gamma_2}$ passing from their fixed points far(they don't share the fixed points) from each other, I believe that $\Gamma= <\gamma_1,\gamma_2>$ from a Kleinian group.

Cross posted on math.stackexchange.

Your writing is unclear. What do you mean by "noncommutative generators"? I know what "noncommuting" means and standard parabolic generators of the figure 8 knot group do not commute. And any nonelementary 2-generated Kleinian group admits a 2-generating set both elements of which are loxodromic.

@MoisheKohan Thank you so much pointing out mistakes, I am new in this area, I very recently started learning cusp hyperbolic 3-manifolds. Noncommutative generators: I mean generators do not commute each other. How I will get always loxodromic generators?

Noncommuting generators is automatic, since the only commutative knot groups are $\mathbb Z$, the fundamental group of the unknot. Similarly, if $M$ is a complete hyperbolic 3-manifold of finite volume, then its fundamental group is never commutative.

@MoisheKohan Why can't  $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ come as a knot group? If we take $\mathbb{H}^3/\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ then what problem will arise?

@Tghosh: no commuting lair of loxodromics can generate a subgroup that acts properly on hyperbolic space. You need to understand this basic exercise if you want to understand the answer to your question.

Did you take an algebraic topology class before trying to learn knot theory and hyperbolic geometry? A standard exercise in algebraic topology is to compute homology of a knot complement. Can you do this?

@MoisheKohan 1st homology group of knot complement is $\mathbb{Z}$

@MoisheKohan now I got your point. So, $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ can't come as a knot group. Thanks

Yes, all hyperbolic three-manifold fundamental groups can be generated by loxodromic elements.  For, suppose that $\Gamma = \{ \gamma_i \}$ is a generating set.  Take $\gamma$, a loxodromic element which is "sufficiently long" compared to the elements $\Gamma$.  Then the set $\{ \gamma \} \cup \{\gamma \cdot \gamma_i\}$ generates and consists only of loxodromic elements.
A more delicate argument will give loxodromic generating sets, of size two, of (say) the twist knot groups.

I think you mean supose $\Gamma=<a,b>$ is a Kleinian group, where $a,b$ both are parabolic elements elements, if $a,b$ are not commute each other then I can always find a loxodromic element $g$ say, so, $\Gamma=<g,g.a,g.b>$, therefore $\Gamma$ is generated by loxdromic elements. Is it?

If $a$ and $b$ are parabolic, commute, and generate a Kleinian group, then the quotient $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ has infinite volume.
